# Occasional error when attempting to set a variable

Tags: html, excel, vba, getelementsbytagname

I'm running into

> "object variable or with block variable not set"

error.

This is occuring when I attempt to set Table = `htmldoc.getElementsbytagname("tr")(116).getelementsbytagname("td")`. It works sometimes, but other times I get this error. Any ideas on how I can avoid running into this error? I noted in my code where the error occurs and included the html below as well.

```
Sub gethourlymaxvalues()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "webaddress"
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.item("Login1_UserName").Value = "username"
        .document.all.item("Login1_Password").Value = "pw"
        .document.all.item("Login1_LoginButton").Click
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .navigate "webaddress"
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Dim htmldoc As Object
        Dim aTable As Object
        Dim r
        Dim c

        Do Until IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set htmldoc = IE.document
        Error 91>> Set aTable = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(116).getElementsByTagName("td") ''Error object variable or with block variable not set''
        r = 0
        c = 0
        For Each TDelement In aTable
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slice").Range("j8").Offset(r, c).Value = TDelement.innerText
            r = r + 1
        Next
        r = 0
        Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub
```

HTML:

```html
  </table>
    </tbody>
    <td>
    <span id="ctl00_PageContent_LblCompany" style="font-family: Verdana;">Company</span></td><td><select name="ctl00$PageContent$cboCompanies" id="ctl00_PageContent_cboCompanies" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$cboCompanies\',\'\')', 0)">
    <option value="AA">AVA</option>
    <option value="CD">CHPD</option>
    <option value="CS1">COMS1</option>
    </select><input name="ctl00$PageContent$cmdViewReport" id="ctl00_PageContent_cmdViewReport" type="submit" value="View Report"><input name="ctl00$PageContent$cmdDownload" id="ctl00_PageContent_cmdDownload" type="submit" value="Download Excel"></td><td><select name="ctl00$PageContent$cboRefresh" id="ctl00_PageContent_cboRefresh" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$cboRefresh\',\'\')', 0)">
    <option value="0">Auto Refresh Off</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="900000">Auto Refresh: 15 Minutes</option>
    <option value="1800000">Auto Refresh: 30 Minutes</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <table id="ctl00_PageContent_Table2" border="0"><tbody>
    </tr><tr style="background-color: palegoldenrod;">
    <td><span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl05_Label50">Estimated Calculated Max Cap</span>
    </td><td>
    <span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl05_Label51">161</span>
    </td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color: beige;">
    <td>
    <span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl06_Label50">Estimated Pond Min Capacity Restriction</span>
    </td><td>
    <span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl06_Label51">159</span>
    </td><td>
    <span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl06_Label52">159</span>
    </td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color: beige;">
    <td><span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdPond_ctl19_Label50">Participant Pond Maximum</span>
    </td><td><span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdPond_ctl19_Label51">2630</span>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The HTML looks like they are using ASP.NET webforms? Is the content dynamic? If so, how do you know there'll always be a 116th `tr` element for all given pages? What exactly is in the 116th `tr` element?

Comment: I'm a little new with scraping html and don't know what webform they are using. I found 116 by trial and error. Do you know of a better way to go about setting this element? Im not sure if its dynamic because I'm been using it with occasional success for the past few days

Comment: I just looked and it does appear that they are using ASP.NET

Comment: I would not try to use ordinal position because I'm very sure the content is rendered dynamically. The names all smells to me ASP.NET Webforms. Rather, I'd try to see if I can use the `class`, the header or something more distinctive, do a find for that instead of hard-coding the ordinal position. Would need to know more about the webpage layout to provide guidance.

Comment: I'll put together some more html code and will post it shortly.

Comment: I just posted more html code hopefully that will help show the layout better. An example of the values I'm trying to retrieve are "Estimated Calculated Max" and the value "161".

Comment: Are you looking for all occurrences of `Estimated Calculated Max` or are you sure there'll be only one per the page? What is `161`? A value you're trying to get or match to?

Comment: There will be just one occurrence of "estimated calculated max" per page. 161 is the max for Hour 1. I'll need to get the max values for each hour of the day so there will be 24 max values.

Comment: As suggested above, i've been attempting to loop to find the relevant tags with no success so far. Any helpful tips?

Comment: There is only one Estimated Calculated Max Cap shown in the HTML. Could you provide HTML for the 24? perhpas using pastebin?